# Custom columns for tiny (400*800) resolution

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

I am really impressed by foundation's grid system.
I am working on a layout in which i need like 12 columns for the screen resolution of `400px` wide.Like a small phone. 
Now **foundation does not give me tiny columns** small is the best i get. **So how can i set specific column sizes for a particular resolution like say tiny?**
thanks

Answer (score 1):

The grid scales down gracefully to the point when even smaller columns become unreasonable.

http://jsfiddle.net/LV339/2/

html:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="small-1 columns"></div>
   <div class="small-1 columns"></div>
   <div class="small-1 columns"></div>
   <div class="small-1 columns"></div>
   <div class="small-1 columns"></div>
   <div class="small-1 columns"></div>
   <div class="small-1 columns"></div>
   <div class="small-1 columns"></div>
   <div class="small-1 columns"></div>
   <div class="small-1 columns"></div>
   <div class="small-1 columns"></div>
   <div class="small-1 columns"></div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.row{
    max-width:400px;
}
.columns{
    height:500px;
}
.columns:nth-child(odd){
    background:red;
}
.columns:nth-child(even){
    background:blue;
}
```